# fromLatLngToPoint is not defined

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am Currently working with Google maps and When I try to customize Google Map tooltip in my code then it gives me an error
**fromLatLngToPoint is not defined**
Have searched and tried some solution but didn't get a solution.

here is my code

```
function initialize() 
  {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      styles: [
        {
          "featureType": "water",
          "stylers": [
            { "color": "#1CA5EA" }
          ]
        },{
          "featureType": "landscape.natural",
          "stylers": [
            { "color": "#EDEDED" }
          ]
        },{
          "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
          "stylers": [
            { "color": "#E0E0E0" }
          ]
        },{
          "featureType": "road.highway",
          "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
          ]
        },{
          "featureType": "poi",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" },
            { "gamma": 0.53 },
            { "saturation": 4 },
            { "lightness": -8 }
          ]
        },{
          "featureType": "road.local",
          "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
          "stylers": [
            { "color": "#B7B7B7" }
          ]
        },{
          "featureType": "poi.school",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [
            { "color": "#1CA5EA" },
            { "saturation": 15 },
            { "lightness": -53 },
            { "weight": 0.1 },
            { "gamma": 0.96 }
          ]
        },{
          "featureType": "poi",
          "elementType": "geometry.fill",
          "stylers": [
            { "gamma": 0.89 },
            { "lightness": -1 },
            { "saturation": -1 },
            { "color": "#878787" }
          ]
        },{
          "featureType": "road.arterial",
          "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "simplified" }
          ]
        },{
          "featureType": "road.local",
          "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "simplified" }
          ]
        },{
        }
      ],
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.70610, 11.97324),
      scrollwheel: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(57.70610, 11.97324),
        map: map,

        title: 'This is us!'
    });
    marker.tooltipContent = 'this content should go inside the tooltip';
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'This is an info window'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
        var point = fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition(), map);
        $('#marker-tooltip').html(marker.tooltipContent + '<br>Pixel coordinates: ' + point.x + ', ' + point.y).css({
            'left': point.x,
                'top': point.y
        }).show();
    });
  }
```

Comment: You're calling fromLatLngToPoint() from nowhere. This method is part of map object. Check this out it helps you out : http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/google-maps-api-v3-convert-latlng-object-to-actual-pixels-point-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fromLatLngToPoint` method is a method of a [Projection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Projection).

```
var point = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition());
```